# Why am I seeing Virtual Memory when Swap is off?

Tags: 20.04, ram, swap, memory-usage

Why am I seeing Virtual Memory when Swap is off? What does this mean?
[image]

I am running from live usb - so swap is off.
[image]

**Edit:**
There are other Q&A's ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688962/whats-the-difference-between-operating-system-swap-and-page/1689119#1689119), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970421/whats-the-difference-between-virtual-memory-and-swap-space)) that explain about Virtual Memory and Swap. Further they seem to bolster the concept that SWAP = VM - RAM. Below diagram from Wiki also bolsters the same.
But this question disproof's it and asks for simple explanation.
[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970421/whats-the-difference-between-virtual-memory-and-swap-space) link. It explains it fairly well.

Comment: Swap and Virtual Memory are different, but related, concepts. Virtual Memory is also used for mapping shared libraries into multiple processes' address space.

Comment: Virtual memory is allocated but the programm hasn't written to it

Comment: @MaxSilvester, you are close. Could you elaborate over an answer.